# Jest SpyOn calls actual method instead of the mocked implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am not understanding why the actual method gets called instead of the mocked implementation?

I mocked **useContext** to return a specific State object. Could this be the problem?

I also tried using mock() and had no luck. Any other jest functions I should try using?

Thanks!

```
// State.ts
export class State {
    public static getInstance(): State {}
    
    public getMessage(): Message | undefined {}

    public fetchMessage(): Promise<void> {}
}
```

```
// StateContextPRovider.tsx
export const StateContext = createContext<State>(State.getInstance());

// withMessageData.tsx
export const withMessageData = <P extends { }>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) => {    
    const WrappedComponent: React.FC<Props> = props => {
        const state: State = useContext(StateContext)
        
        const [message, setMessage] = useState<PaymentRiskMessage | undefined>(state.getMessage());
        
        useEffect(() => {
            state.fetchMessage()
                .then(() => {
                    setMessage(state.getMessage());
                });
        }, []);

        return <Component {...(props as P)} message={message}/>;
    };
    
    return WrappedComponent;
};
```

```
describe("Test", () => {
        jest.spyOn(React, "useContext").mockReturnValue(new State());
        jest.spyOn(State.prototype, "fetchMessage")
            .mockImplementation(() => {
                console.log("why won't this run?")
                return Promise.resolve();
            });
        jest.spyOn(State.prototype, "getMessage")
            .mockImplementation(mockGetPaymentRiskMessage);

        test("", () => {
            const MockComponent: React.FC<{ mockProp: string }> = props => {
                return <View {...props} />;
            };
            const WrappedMockComponent = withMessageData(MockComponent);

            act(() => {
                TestRenderer.create(<WrappedMockComponent mockProp={"mockData"} />);
            });
        });
    });
```